# What is the purpose of the "quotaUser" parameter on BigQuery API?

Tags: google-bigquery, quotas

According to the [BigQuery client API reference](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/bigquery/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/bigquery/Bigquery.Jobs.Insert.html) (using the Java API as example), there is a "quotaUser" parameter which can be set on inserting a new Job on BigQuery:

> Available to use for quota purposes for server-side applications. Can
>   be any arbitrary string assigned to a user, but should not exceed 40
>   characters. Overrides userIp if both are provided.

.. and a "userIp" parameter:

> IP address of the site where the request originates. Use this if you want to enforce per-user limits.

... but there is no mention to that parameters at the [BigQuery Rest API reference](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs).

How do those parameters work? Do they transfer the 20-concurrent-jobs quota to the user instead of my server? Or any other quota defined [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quota-policy)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These parameters are provided by the google APIs service that BigQuery uses, but are not actually used by BigQuery. You should ignore these parameters when using BigQuery. Most BigQuery queries are applied at the Project level, which would not be affected anyway.

Comment: Is there a way to improve the 20-concurrent-jobs quota? 20 is a quite low number for server-side applications (from where the queries are launched).

Comment: When queries are run at Batch Priority, they are not subject to the 20-concurrent-jobs quota. Instead, when you submit queries too fast, they will queue on the server until they can be processed. More details at https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/querying-data#batchqueries.

Comment: @MichaelSheldon Yes, but batch queries are intended for long headless queries, which the user doesn't bother (much) on waiting for like hours to see the results. Not suitable for a user-facing app. I hope they rise the number of allowed concurrent jobs soon.

Comment: Created the [issue #187](https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=187): Allow projects to pay for more concurrent interactive queries.